# React Native - React app using incorrect path for index.js source

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am learning react native by working on a simple project for Android (on Windows 10).
Things were working fine and results showing correctly on Android simulator.

But now when ever I run my code on the simulator it shows this error:

[image]

I am not sure why it says "The resource D:\index.js was not found". My index.js file is not in that directory. It is in D:\folder1\folder2\index.js.

Does anyone know why it is referring to an incorrect path ?

I am of course running react-native run-android from the project folder (ie D:\folder1\folder2).

Thanks,

Comment: Did you accidentally change the location of your `index.js`. In any case just go to your `package.json` to point it to your current `index.js` and you should be good to go

Comment: How to do that ? I don't see how to point to the file in package.json. It mostly shows versions of different items